# OpenRefine: after reconciliation, I want to retrieve the title of Wikidata items in other languages

Tags: openrefine

In the same way I can obtain geographic coordinates for, let's say a list of cities, I'd like to create columns in OpenRefine with the names of those cities in different languages (Venice, Venezia, Wenecja, Wenedig…). Is it possible? Apparently there is no property like that in Wikidata.

[Wikidata screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0KUw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch those using special property codes in OpenRefine. To fetch the label in a given language, find out the language code for it, and then prepend `L` to it. For instance, `Lit` will give you the label in Italian.
You can also do `Dfr` (French description) or `Ade` (German aliases).

This is documented at https://wikidata.reconci.link/